# How do I iterate variables to pass into a http header params for further iteration

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have 2 json api's that I am requesting; search and extended profile.

The first one gives me some search results for profiles. The search results have a "memberid" number `ps['id']` for each profile found.

I want to pass and iterate those memberid's to the next json api for the extended profile information for each member. The memberid's has to be passed into the profile_params. As it is now, only 1 memberid is being passed and stored and therefore I only get the first extended profile and not all from the search.

My code is like this:

```
# Search for profiles
search_response = requests.post('https://api_search_for_profiles', headers=search_headers, data=search_params)
search_json = json.dumps(search_response.json(), indent=2)
search_data = json.loads(search_json)

memberid = []
for ps in (search_data['data']['content']):
    memberid = str(ps['id']) # These memberid's I want to pass all found to the profile_params.
    print('UserID: ' + str(ps['roomNo']))
    print('MemberID: ' + str(ps['id']))
    print('Username: ' + ps['nickName'])

# Extended profile info
profile_headers = {
    'x-auth-token': f'{token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'okhttp/3.11.0',
}

profile_params = {
    'id': '',
    'token': f'{token}',
    'memberId': f'{memberid}', # where I want each memberid from the search to go
    'roomNo': ''
}

profile_response = requests.post('https://api_extended_profile_information', headers=profile_headers, data=profile_params)
profile_json = json.dumps(profile_response.json(), indent=2)
profile_data = json.loads(profile_json)
pfd = profile_data['data'] # main data

userid = str(pfd['roomNo'])
username = pfd['nickName']
gender = str(pfd['gender'])
level = str(pfd['memberLevel'])

# Here I will iterate through each profiles with the corresponding memberid and print.
```

The json output for search is like this, snippet:

```
{
  "code": 0,
  "data": {
    "content": [
      {
        "id": 1359924,
        "memberLevel": 1,
        "nickName": "akuntesting dgt",
        "roomNo": 1820031
      },
      {
        "id": 2607179,                
        "memberLevel": 1,
        "nickName": "testingsyth",        
        "roomNo": 3299390        
      }, 
      # ... and so on
```

Comment: Does the extended profile api allow a post request with more than one memberid or are you required to have a separate request for each memberid?

Comment: One for each I think

Comment: You need to verify it; one for each is simpler.

Comment: I don't know how to verify it. I don't know how to post request more than one memberid. For now it has only taken one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the post request takes only one memberid, the following is a simplified version of your code designed to handle only the issue of multiple memberids. Starting here:

```
memberids = []
for ps in (search_data['data']['content']):
    memberid = str(ps['id'])
    memberids.append(memberid)

for memberid in memberids:
    profile_params = {'memberId': memberid}
    profile_response = requests.post('https://api_extended_profile_information', headers=profile_headers, data=profile_params)
    #the rest of your code goes here inside the loop
```

Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: I works like a charm. Where I couldn't find logic on how to do this before, it is now very obvious and simple when knowing hehe. Thank you!